# Error in index.php file to create Rest Api using Slim Framework

Tags: php, slim

I copy the slimeframework qiuck code and paste in index.php but when i run in localhost(http://localhost/MyApiFirstTry/public/hello/testMessage),

it show some errors ..

like this

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException: Not found. in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApiFirstTry\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php:93 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApiFirstTry\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Routing\RouteRunner.php(72): 
Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware->performRouting(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #1 
C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApiFirstTry\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81):
 Slim\Routing\RouteRunner->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #2 
C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApiFirstTry\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(211): 
Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApiFirstTry\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\App.php(195): 
Slim\App->handle(Object(Slim\Psr7\Request)) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApiFirstTry\public\index.php(17): Slim\App->run() #5 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApiFirstTry\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\RoutingMiddleware.php on line 93
```

how i can solve errors ..

Comment: if you expecting help, you have to add some code, which causes that issue without that nobody will be able to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The Problem

Your current document root directory in XAMPP is `http://localhost/`. But in your application, it should be `http://localhost/MyApiFirstTry/public/`. That's why you're getting **HttpNotFoundException** exception.

It will work when you prefix your route with `/MyApiFirstTry/public/`:

```
app->get('/MyApiFirstTry/public/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $name = $args['name'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");
    return $response;
});
```

But that's not how it works. You shouldn't be doing this. In the [Slim documentation](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/web-servers.html):

> It is typical to use the front-controller pattern to funnel
>   appropriate HTTP requests received by your web server to a single PHP
>   file.

You should configure your web server to send HTTP requests to your PHP front-controller file (`/index.php`).

### The Solution

Go to `C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApiFirstTry\` directory and run the following command in terminal to start localhost web server:

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t public
```

Then navigate to `http://localhost:8888` in your browser.

Read more about [PHP built-in server](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/start/web-servers.html#php-built-in-server).

Answer (score 1):

in my case i had similar problem so i add following code in sample web service

```
$middleware = $app->addErrorMiddleware(true,true,true);
```

so my final output of sample code is

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
$app = AppFactory::create();
//print_r($app);
$middleware = $app->addErrorMiddleware(true,true,true);
$app->get('/retrofit2/public/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $name = $args['name'];
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello how are you $name");
    return $response;
});
$app->run();
```